# Reading a binary file into a boolean array using Python's struct package

Tags: python, struct, binary, boolean

I am trying to read a binary file (only 32 bits long) into a boolean array. It worked just fine when I followed:

[Using Python How can I read the bits in a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576712/using-python-how-can-i-read-the-bits-in-a-byte)

However, when I try to use the struct package I get a different results:

```
_fmt = '32?'

with open(filename, mode='rb') as fp:
    content = struct.unpack(fmt, fp.read(struct.calcsize(fmt))
```

I would like to understand why.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `'32?'` indicates 32 bytes, not 32 bits.

Comment: So I guess there is no way to read an array of booleans (1 bit) from a file directly using struct.

Comment: Right; `struct` packs and unpacks bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Bitarray might help you: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray

Or the recipes here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitArrays