# Python: Extracting bits from a byte

Tags: python, byte, bit

I'm reading a binary file in python and the documentation for the file format says:

> Flag (in binary)Meaning
>
> 1 nnn nnnn      Indicates that there is one data byte to follow
>                   that is to be duplicated nnn nnnn (127 maximum)
>                   times.
>
> 0 nnn nnnn      Indicates that there are nnn nnnn bytes of image
>                   data to follow (127 bytes maximum) and that
>                   there are no duplications.
>
> n 000 0000      End of line field. Indicates the end of a line
>                   record. The value of n may be either zero or one.
>                   Note that the end of line field is required and
>                   that it is reflected in the length of line record
>                   field mentioned above.

When reading the file I'm expecting the byte I'm at to return `1 nnn nnnn` where the `nnn nnnn` part should be 50.

I've been able to do this using the following:

```
flag = byte >> 7
numbytes = int(bin(byte)[3:], 2)
```

But the numbytes calculation feels like a cheap workaround.

Can I do more bit math to accomplish the calculation of numbytes?

How would you approach this?

Comment: related: [Using Python How can I read the bits in a byte?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2576712/4279)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can strip off the leading bit using a mask ANDed with a byte from file. That will leave you with the value of the remaining bits:

```
mask =  0b01111111
byte_from_file = 0b10101010
value = mask & byte_from_file
print bin(value)
>> 0b101010
print value
>> 42
```

I find the binary numbers easier to understand than hex when doing bit-masking.

EDIT: Slightly more complete example for your use case:

```
LEADING_BIT_MASK =  0b10000000
VALUE_MASK = 0b01111111

values = [0b10101010, 0b01010101, 0b0000000, 0b10000000]

for v in values:
    value = v & VALUE_MASK
    has_leading_bit = v & LEADING_BIT_MASK
    if value == 0:
        print "EOL"
    elif has_leading_bit:
        print "leading one", value
    elif not has_leading_bit:
        print "leading zero", value
```

Comment: Thanks. I too prefer the binary numbers in this case.

Comment: @EvanBorgstrom On Python 3, you could write: `data = b'\xaa\x55\x00\x80'` and `for byte in data: ...`. Don't use `bytes` name, it is a builtin type.

Answer (score 28):

The classic approach of checking whether a bit is set, is to use binary "and" operator, i.e.

```
x = 10 # 1010 in binary
if x & 0b10:  # explicitly: x & 0b0010 != 0
    print('First bit is set')
```

To check, whether n^th bit is set, use the power of two, or better bit shifting

```
def is_set(x, n):
    return x & 2 ** n != 0 

    # a more bitwise- and performance-friendly version:
    return x & 1 << n != 0

is_set(10, 1) # 1 i.e. first bit - as the count starts at 0-th bit
>>> True
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question. Given byte = 178, how would you extract flag == 1 & numbytes == 50?

Comment: +1: but one doesn't need the !=0 part, `if x&0b10` should be sufficient.

Comment: `!= 0` is not quite as bad as `== True`, but it is close. :)

Comment: [_Explicit is better than implicit_](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) so `x & 0b10 != 0` is fine by me

Comment: Consider this: bin(178) == 10110010; If I uderstood correctly, you need to return all bytes starting from i.e. 5th byte. Then 178 & (2^5 - 1), should do the trick, because in this case 10110010 & 00011111 == 00010010

Comment: `print('First bit is set')` – the word *first* is **very** confusing here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of int(bin(byte)[3:], 2), you could simply use: int(bin(byte>>1),2)

Answer (score 1):

If I read your description correctly:

```
if (byte & 0x80) != 0:
    num_bytes = byte & 0x7F
```

Answer (score 1):

there you go:

```
class ControlWord(object):
    """Helper class to deal with control words.

    Bit setting and checking methods are implemented.
    """
    def __init__(self, value = 0):
        self.value = int(value)
    def set_bit(self, bit):
        self.value |= bit
    def check_bit(self, bit):
        return self.value & bit != 0
    def clear_bit(self, bit):    
        self.value &= ~bit
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure I got you correctly, but if I did, this should do the trick:

```
>>> x = 154 #just an example
>>> flag = x >> 1
>>> flag
1
>>> nb = x & 127
>>> nb
26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
def GetVal(b):
   # mask off the most significant bit, see if it's set
   flag = b & 0x80 == 0x80
   # then look at the lower 7 bits in the byte.
   count = b & 0x7f
   # return a tuple indicating the state of the high bit, and the 
   # remaining integer value without the high bit.
   return (flag, count)

>>> testVal = 50 + 0x80
>>> GetVal(testVal)
(True, 50)
```