# Start at offset from beginning of file and unpack 4 byte word

Tags: python, file-io, struct, format, unpack

With Python, given an offset say 250 bytes, how would I jump to this position in a file and store a 32bit binary value?

My issue is `read()` returns a string and I'm not sure if I'm able to properly advance to the valid offset having done that. Also, experimenting with `struct.unpack()` it's demanding a length equivalent to the specified format. How do I grab only the immediate following data according to what's expected of the specified format? And what's the format for a 32bit int?
Ex. I wrote a string >32 characters and thought I could grab the initial 32 bits and store them as a single 32 bit int by using `'<qqqq'`, this was incorrect needless to say.

Comment: possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576712/using-python-how-can-i-read-the-bits-in-a-byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open("input.bin","rb") as f:
    f.seek(250) #offset 
    print struct.unpack("<l",f.read(4)) #grabs one little endian 32 bit long
```

if you wanted 4, 32 bit ints you would use

```
print struct.unpack("<llll",f.read(16))
```

if you just want to grab the next 32bit int

```
print struct.unpack_from("<l",f)[0]
```

Comment: The second argument to the `unpack()` call is missing.